# How to do this guitar technique?

Tags: guitar, technique

I'm a beginner, what is the name of this technique?

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this ? Actually, I've an idea, but it's not working, so I don't know if I'm right or not.

Comment: Is this a piece that is to be played with a bottle neck?

Comment: So, what is your idea?

Comment: It come from https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/albert-gyorfi-the-scientist-tab-s402338t0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a slide up and down to me, but from 0 fret to 2 and back to 0 isn't easy. So, it , being legato playing, might be a hammer on and pull off. On 3rd string, play open, then hammer on to 2nd fret, then pull off, using the fretting finger, back to open note.

Comment: It would explain why I'm not able to do it if it's not so easy. :/

Comment: The notation certainly calls for a slide and not hammer-on/pull-off. Slides from open strings are common in playing with bottlenecks. I have never seen it elsewhere though, hence my question above.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a slide to me. Hammer and pull off .

Comment: It's totally hammer on and pull off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhD9wjuw33E